# Why executable grows so much after compiling it with static library?

Tags: c++, boost, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have just tried now to compile my small test application with static libboost system library as such :

```
$ g++ -I ~/lib/boost-1.56/include main.cpp -o main -L~/lib/boost-1.56/lib/ -static  -lboost_system
```

before that I have compiled it without static libraries:

```
$ g++ -I ~/lib/boost-1.56/include main.cpp -o main -L~/lib/boost-1.56/lib/ -lboost_system
```

The size difference is way bigger than the size difference between the libraries versions:

- dynamically linked - 40K
- statically linked - 1.6M

libboost libraries in `~/lib/boost-1.56/lib`

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 USER USER 218K sie 31 14:44 libboost_filesystem.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 USER USER   29 sie 31 14:43 libboost_filesystem.so -> libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0
-rwxrwxr-x 1 USER USER 115K sie 31 14:43 libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 USER USER  49K sie 31 14:44 libboost_system.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 USER USER   25 sie 31 14:43 libboost_system.so -> libboost_system.so.1.56.0
-rwxrwxr-x 1 USER USER  20K sie 31 14:43 libboost_system.so.1.56.0
```

Why is there such a huge difference in size?

Answer (score 4):

Static libraries mean that instead of your executable linking to external library files (on Windows they are DLLs), they are now lumped into your actual executable. This is a good thing if there are reasons you don't want to distribute DLLs separately, but it also completely wastes the benefits of DLLs such as being able to swap them out individually instead of redistributing all of your application, as well as letting multiple applications use common code stored in just one place on a system.

And considering how big Boost is, it's not surprising how huge your executable file got.